# How can I resize a slider in php website?

Tags: php

Hello I have got this php website to work upon.
But I am not able to change the slider to get it displayed horizontally instead of its vertical view.
Actually I am not getting what to change.
So if anyone can help me out will be appreciated.

for reference: http://www.smsconsortium.com/

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To help you out we'd need to see your code and maybe where your script is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `width:100%;` to `.flex-viewport`:

```
.flex-viewport {
    width:100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response but there is no command for flex-viewpost so what should i do?

Comment: Hello thank you for answering my previous question. I have got one more question to ask.I have got one more question to ask i.e I am using the following code: <div class="contact_detail">
         <div class="inner">
          <div class="con_pic"><img src="images/email_icon.png" alt="" /></div>
          <h3 class="left_title">Email</h3>
             <div class="address">
              <a class="mail" href="mailto:<?php echo ADMINMAIL; ?>"><?php echo ADMINMAIL; ?></a>
</div></div>             How can i change the ADMINMAIL from info@smsconsortium.com to legal@smsconsortium.com??

Comment: Look for a `define('ADMINMAIL', 'info@smsconsortium.com')` somewhere in your code, prob a config of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

Add following css to your project's css.

```
.slides{
display:flex;
}
.flex-viewport{
width:100%;
}
```

That should fix your issue

Comment: why down vote ? this is exactly what he wanted look here ... https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2018/03/12/oAse.png

Comment: sometimes i think its useless to answer to this questions ppl just do not know what they want and downvote you for no reasons ....

Comment: .slides{
display:flex;
} will break it.https://imgur.com/PZqPOli.png Dont upvote whats wrong, it will confuse the OP.